# Elasticsearch Nested Type Recursive

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are using Spring Data Elasticsearch for the development of our search mechanism.  I'm just wondering how can we have a parent-child mapping of the same type/document?  The code is more like this:

```
@Document(indexName = "customer", type = "catalogue_item")
public class CatalogueItemDocument {
...

@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
private Set<CatalogueItemDocument> children;

...

}
```

Would this be possible? If not, how can I achieve this using the parent-child implementation suggested by the Elasticsearch [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html).

Comment: I'm trying to solve this exact issue, did you figure it out?